# How to perform few calculations within two columns for a given primary key

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, teradata

Query is edited as asked by fellow contributors.  Thanks a lot in advance.
For a given primary key (id_pk), let's assume following are the values:

```
 1. id_pk | code_col| amt_col
 2. abc   | 10  | 1000
 3. abc   | 11  | 5
 4. abc   | 12  | 10
 5. abc   | 13  | 20
```

Now, I need to check if, for the given primary key called 'abc', there exists the value called '10' under the column 'code_col'.
If this condition satisfies, then the following needs to be performed:

1. For the same primary key abc, for the code_col value of 11, substract the amt_col value (i.e., 5) from amt_col value of 10 (i.e., 1000). So the ultimate value is 0 should be updated in the second row of the above table.
2. For the same primary key abc, for the code_col value of 12, substract the amt_col value (i.e., 10) from amt_col value of 10 (i.e., 1000). So the ultimate value is 0 should be updated in the third row of the above table.
3. For the same primary key abc, for the code_col value of 13, substract the amt_col value (i.e., 20) from amt_col value of 10 (i.e., 1000). So the ultimate value is -865 (the remaining) should be updated in the fourth/last row of the above table.

The results should be like the below:

```
 1. id_pk | col1| col2
 2. abc   | 10  | 0
 3. abc   | 11  | 0
 4. abc   | 12  | 0
 5. abc   | 13  | -965
```

Hope this is clear.  I need to achieve this validation in Teradata (Query / Cursor / StoredProcedure / macros/ anything else is also welcomed.

If the texts appear so bold, kindly do copy paste the contents in the Notepad++ as I used the same to post it here.

Comment: Just so this is clear... You want to order your records for each id_pk by `col1` and then starting with `1000` subtract the `col2` value cumulatively storing that value in a new column and setting `col2` to 0. Is that right?

Comment: And if this is right, why `1000` and why skip the first record where `col1` is `10`?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  Where does the magic 1000 come from?  What does "update it as 0" means after  you have done the calculation?

Comment: Hello JNevill and Gordon, thanks a lot for this.  I've updated the post and corrected the first value from 0 to 1000.  Sorry for the mishap...

Comment: How you are getting 0 for first and second row? Show the calculation please.

Comment: Hello mkRabbani,  Pl. read the text statements, we need to substract the amount from the first value amount and it'll become zero.  Hope you got it?

Comment: Not yet :( can you please show the calculation like, 100-5-20 = 0?

Comment: If the value of amt_col is 1000 for the first record (i.e., code_col of '10'), then we need to reduce whatever amount is available in the 2nd record.  So here, it's 5 and when we reduce it, it should be going down upto 0.  Hope this makes sense?  If you look into the statements and my results, it'll be more clearer...I guess.. Please confirm.  Thanks

Comment: What if there's a `code_col = 9` or a 2nd `10`? *substract the amt_col value (i.e., 5) from amt_col value of 10 (i.e., 1000). So the ultimate value is 0* If I calculate `1000-5` it's 995 not 0.

Comment: Your calculations make no sense at all. Why `865` as final result?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, the expectation is second row and third row should become 0 and the whatever the remaining amount, we've to put it in the last/fourth row.  Of course, there can be multiple scenarios like instead of 5,10 and 20, in the 2nd,3rd,4th rows respectively many other values will be there, I'll use the same logic given by our helpers here.  Hope it makes sense?

Comment: Why is `1000 - 5 - 10 - 20 = -865` instead of `965`? And I meant the `code_col`: what if the lowest value is less than `10`, should this `id_pk` be included and what's the expected result then?

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, it's -965.  Sorry for the typo..in more tensed situation:(.  Also, I need the logic.  My requirement is if the first condition satisfies (code_val of 10 existing), then whatever its respective amount (from first amt_col value), they should be deducting the 2nd, 3rd and whatever is remaining, it should be updated in the fourth/last row.  Hope this is more clear?

Comment: Things are bit clear now. Is there any real column like you make serial 1 to 5 to determine the last row among/for abc?

Comment: We can consider the condition - col1 having the value of 13 as the last row.  This is for every primary key.  Hope makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is some ambiguity here (where does the 1000 come from), (Why skip the first record?), etc... here's a quick stab at a cumulative sum that gets you in the ballpark:

```
SELECT id_pk, 
    col1, 
    0 AS col2, 
    -1000 + SUM(SUM(col2)) OVER (PARTITION BY id_pk ORDER BY col1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS col3
FROM t1
GROUP BY id_pk, col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to match your requirements:

```
SELECT id_pk, code_col
  ,CASE
     WHEN code_col = Max(code_col) Over (PARTITION BY id_pk) -- "last" row?
     THEN -- negative code 10 amount
       Max(CASE WHEN code_col = 10 THEN -amt_col*2 end) Over (PARTITION BY id_pk)
          --  plus the sum of all other amounts
       + Sum(amt_col) Over (PARTITION BY id_pk)
     ELSE 0
   END
FROM tab
QUALIFY -- only ids with a code 10
   Max(CASE WHEN code_col = 10 THEN code_col end) Over (PARTITION BY id_pk) = 10
```

Comment: Hi dnoeth, jus a thing - is there a way to create an alias for a column value not for the entire column itself?

Comment: @ArunBee: What do you mean by *alias for a column value*?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general logic you can convert to Teradata syntax.

```
SELECT id_pk,
code_col col1,
CASE 
    WHEN code_col = 13 THEN (Sum_10 - Sum_Other)
    ELSE 0
END col2
FROM your_table A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_pk, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN code_col = 10 THEN amt_col ELSE NULL END) Sum_10,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code_col <> 10 THEN amt_col ELSE NULL END) Sum_Other 
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY id_pk
)B ON A.id_pk = B.id_pk
```

Alternatively, you can try this below logic as well-

```
SELECT 
A.id_pk,
A.code_col col1,
CASE 
    WHEN A.code_col = 13 THEN
        (SELECT amt_col FROM your_table WHERE code_col = 10 AND id_pk = A.id_pk)
        -
        (SELECT SUM(amt_col) FROM your_table WHERE code_col <> 10 AND id_pk = A.id_pk)
    ELSE 0
END col2
FROM your_table A
```